# "Error in /turbo_modules/react-router@6.2.2/umd/react-router.production.min.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {


return (
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <Header />

    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/project" component={Project} />
  </div>
</Router>


 );
}

function Header() {


return (
<div className="header">
  <p>this header</p>
</div>
);}

function Home() {
return <h1>HOME</h1>;
}

function Project() {
 return <h1>PROJECT</h1>;
}

function About() {
return <h1>About</h1>;
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to use "react-router-dom" but I am facing an unexpected error, my page is not loaded in the browser or it is showing an error which is "Error in /turbo_modules/react-router@6.2.2/umd/react-router.production.min.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `react-router-dom@6` installed then there are at least a couple of issues:

1. The `Route` components API changed and all routed content is rendered on a single `element` prop instead of the v5 `component` prop (*or `render` and `children` function props*).
2. All `Route` components ***must*** be rendered by a `Routes` component. `Routes` is the spiritual successor to the v5 `Switch` component and handles the route matching/rendering.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/project" element={<Project />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```